# What is the actual effect of variable BitMask in the function CeilLog2?

Tags: c++

Here is the definition of the function:

```
inline uint32_t CountLeadingZeros(uint32_t Val)
{
    // Use BSR to return the log2 of the integer
    unsigned long Log2;
    if (_BitScanReverse(&Log2, Val) != 0)
    {
        return 31 - Log2;
    }
    return 32;
}

inline uint32_t CeilLog2(uint32_t Val)
{
    int BitMask = ((int)(CountLeadingZeros(Val) << 26)) >> 31;
    return (32 - CountLeadingZeros(Val - 1)) & (~BitMask);
}
```

Here is my hypothesis:

The range of the return value of the function CountLeadingZeros is [0, 32]. When the input Val is equal to 0, CountLeadingZeros(Val) << 26 should be 1000,0000,....,0000,0000.

Since the left hand side of operator >> is signed number, the result of >> 32 would be 1111,1111,....,1111,1111. When Val is not equal to 0, the BitMask would always be 0000,0000,....,0000,0000.

So I guess that the utility of variable BitMask is to let the function return 0 when the input Val is zero.

But the question is that when I pass an -1 to this function, it would be cast to 4294967295, result in the output become 32.

Is my hypothesis right?

I have seen this implementation many times in the RayTracing renderer on the github.

What is actual effect of BitMask here? Confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the left hand side of operator `>>` is signed number, the result of `>> 32` would be `1111,1111,....,1111,1111`. When `Val` is not equal to 0, the `BitMask` would always be `0000,0000,....,0000,0000`.

Your analysis is absolutely correct: `BitMask` is either all ones when `Val` is non-zero; otherwise it is all zeros. You can eliminate `BitMask` with a simple conditional:

```
return Val ? (32 - CountLeadingZeros(Val - 1)) : 0;
```

This does not create new branching, because the conditional replaces the `if` of `CountLeadingZeros`.

> But the question is that when I pass an -1 to this function, it would be cast to 4294967295, result in the output become 32.

Function takes an unsigned number, so you should pass 0xFFFFFFFF, not -1 (representation of negatives is implementation-defined). In this case the return value should be 32, the correct value of log<sub>2</sub> ceiling for this value.